# gitignore how to ignore a file and not a directory tree

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have a weird behavior with my `.gitignore` file

My project tree looks like this

```
abc
 |
 |-> inc
 |-> src
 |-> obj---
 |        |-> abc (The exeutable file)
```

I would like that the **abc executable** will be ignored so I added `abc` to my `.gitignore` file.
but now, the whole abc tree is ignored.

How can I specify that I want to ignore only a file called abc, and not a directory ?

p.s

My `.gitignore` file:

```
*.so
*.o
*.a
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the path:

```
obj/abc
```

Comment: Solves the issue but not the problem, because if for instance there's a obj/abc directory, than it will be also ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a “negative” pattern in your `.gitignore` file:

```
abc
!abc/
```